# send status updates from function in C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, events, asynchronous, delegates

i have a very large function in my C++ dll which performs a lot of tasks.
we are calling it from a c# wrapper and it takes about 20sec for the c++ function to complete.
i want to change the way we run it.
my idea is 
1.to call the c++ function async and 
2. every time a task withing the C++ function is completed, i want to send the "task1 completed" message to C# function and display it to the user so that they know what is going on in the background.

any ideas how to execute this? i looked up several examples but feeling confused. i want to know if anyone has done this. looking for some pointers.

EX:  C++ code

```
int  CppLibrary::ExecuteWorkflow( param1,param2, param3,param4,param5)
{
task1;
task2;
task3;
task4;
task5;

}

calling the C++ function from C# wrapper:

[DllImport(_dllLocation)]
public static extern int ExecuteWorkflow( param1,param2, param3,param4,param5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates in C# to call your C++ wrapper, then use either "invoke" or "beginInvoke" depending on your situation.

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but can you elaborate? you suggest i use delegates in my c# wrapper. but where do i use invoke or begininvoke? i want to send status messages from my c++ function to c# wrapper. so how do i send it from c++ and how do i capture the messages in c#? please understand i never used either c++ or event delegates before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export your C++ function using a C-like name (export "C" __declspec(dllexport))
2. Create a DllImport for your library call using DllImport.
3. Create a thread and invoke the import with your callback logic (i.e. Task.Run with delegate).

Comment: I think you got it backwards.

Comment: Hi. i'm doing the first 2 steps you suggested. can you elaborate the 3rd step? i know how to use threads in c#. but i want to show status messages sent from c++. how do i do it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the a wrapper class for P/Invoke C++ function. Hope can help you.

```
class CSUnmangedTestClass : IDisposable
{
    #region P/Invokes

    [DllImport(@"E:\VS2012Tests\test\Debug\DllImport.dll", EntryPoint="#1")]
    private static extern IntPtr Foo_Create();

    [DllImport(@"E:\VS2012Tests\test\Debug\DllImport.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int Foo_Bar(IntPtr pFoo);

    [DllImport(@"E:\VS2012Tests\test\Debug\DllImport.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void Foo_Delete(IntPtr pFoo);

    #endregion

    #region Members
    // variable to hold the C++ class's this pointer
    private IntPtr m_pNativeObject;
    #endregion

    public CSUnmangedTestClass()
    {
        this.m_pNativeObject = Foo_Create();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool bDisposing)
    {
        if (this.m_pNativeObject != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Foo_Delete(m_pNativeObject);
            this.m_pNativeObject = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        if (bDisposing)
        {
            // No need to call the finalizer since we've now cleaned up the unmanged memory
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    ~CSUnmangedTestClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #region Wrapper methods

    public int Bar()
    {
        return Foo_Bar(m_pNativeObject);
    }

    #endregion
}
```